# Rails 4: sync model changing and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I am new one in rails and I can't understand one thing about `models` and `migrations`: is there way to chase automatically changing in models and apply it to db?

I have model User (and corresponding table in db) with two properties - name and email.

After that I:

1. added new property 'password' to model
2. created new migration where use add_column

Is there way to run fairy [command_name] to synchronize model's changing with migration to prevent errors and avoid step 2?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to solve this problem is to create and run the migration manually before you change the code. That way the password column is already in the database and you won't run into any errors.

Migrations allow you to add that column separately from when you implement it in the rest of the project.